# Using perl `my` within actual function arguments

Tags: perl

I want to use perl to build a document graph as readably as possible. For re-use of nodes, I want to refer to nodes using variables (or constants, if that is easier). The following code works and illustrates the idea with node types represented by literals or factory function calls to `a` and `b`. (For simple demo purposes, the functions do not create nodes but just return a string.)

```
sub a (@) {
    return sprintf "a(%s)", join( ' ', @_ );
}   

sub b (@) {
    return sprintf "b(%s)", join( ' ', @_ );
}   

printf "The document is: %s\n", a(
    "declare c=",
    $c = 1, 
    $e = b( 
        "use",      
        $c,         
        "to declare d=",
        $d = $c + 1 
    ),      
    "use the result",
    $d,     
    "and document the procedure",
    $e      
);
```

The actual and expected output of this is `The document is: a(declare c= 1 b(use 1 to declare d= 2) use the result 2 and document the procedure b(use 1 to declare d= 2))`.

My problem arises because I want to `use strict` in the whole program so that variables like `$c`, `$d`, `$e` must be declared using `my`. I can, of course, write somewhere close to the top of the text `my ( $c, $d, $e );`. It would be more efficient at edit-time when I could use the `my` keyword directly at the first mention of the variable like so:

```
…
printf "The document is: %s\n", a(
    "declare c=",
    my $c = 1,
    my $e = b(
        "use",      
        $c,         
        "to declare d=",
        my $d = $c + 1
    ),      
    "use the result",
    $d,     
    "and document the procedure",
    $e      
);
```

This would be kind of my favourite syntax. Unfortunately, this code yields several `Global symbol "…" requires explicit package name` errors. (Moreover, according to documentation, `my` does not return anything.)

I have the idea of such use of `my` from uses like in `open my $file, '<', 'filename.txt' or die;` or in `for ( my $i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i ) {…}` where declaration and definition go in one.

Since the nodes in the graph are constants, it is acceptable to use something else than lexical variables. (But I think perl's built-in mechanims are strongest and most efficient for lexical variables, which is why I am inclined into this direction.)

My current idea to solve the issue is to define a function named something like `define` which behind the scenes would manipulate the current set of lexical variables using `PadWalker` or similar. Yet this would not allow me to use a natural perl like syntax like `$c = 1`, which would be my preferred syntax.

Comment: So do you want a named variable (`$c`) to be seen only inside the call itself (parenthesis), or also inside the sub ?  The example only makes use of `$c` inside the call statement (to invoke `b()`).

Comment: It is sufficient to see the declared variable in the function arguments (parenthesis), no need to be visible in function bodies {code}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> according to documentation, my does not return anything

The documentation doesn't say that, and it's not the case.

Haven't you ever done `my $x = 123;`? If so, you've assigned to the result of `my $x`. `my` simply returns the newly created variable as an lvalue (assignable value), so `my $x` simply returns `$x`.

> Unfortunately, this code yields several [strict vars] errors.

Symbols (variables) created by `my` are only visible starting with the following statement.

For better of for worse, it allows the following:

```
my $x = 123;

{
   my $x = $x;
   $x *= 2;
   say $x;   # 246
}

say $x;   # 123
```

> I want to use perl to build a document graph as readably as possible.

So why not do that? Right now, you are building a string, not a graph. Build a graph of objects that resolve to a string after the graph has been constructed. You can build those object with a tree of sub calls (`declare( c => [ use( c => ... ), ... ] )`). I'd give a better example, but the grammar of what you are generating isn't clear to me.

Comment: return value: you are right, I was misled by the statement in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_my.htm which claims “This function does not return any value.”

Comment: I like your explanation why the behaviour of `my` makes sense in other contexts.

Comment: Declaring the variable is a compile-time effect, and returning the variable is a run-time effect. The *reason* declarations only come into effect for the next statement is probably because applying run-time evaluation order to compile-time effects is too complicated. The snippet I showed is merely something you can do as a result.

Comment: Are you sure that `declare( c => [ use( c => ... ), ... ] )` can build a general graph? I believe it is only a tree. My problem arises when I want to re-use nodes in several places, so I at least may have diamonds in the graph. Circles will probably not arise in my application, though I am not completely sure (in which case explicit memory management might become necessary…).

Comment: With a suitable definition for `declare`, yes. // Not a problem. Two nodes can refer to the same value. Just like two opcodes in a program can refer to the same var

Answer (score 3):

I am not certain of the exact need but here's one simple way for similar manipulations.

The example in the OP wants a named variable inside the function call statement itself, so that it can be used later in that statement for another call etc. If you must have it that way then you can use a `do` block to work out your argument list

```
func1(  
    do { 
        my $x = 5;
        my $y = func2($x);  # etc 
        say "Return from the do block what is then passed as arguments..."; 
        $x, $y
    }
);
```

This allows you to do things of the kind that your example indicates.<sup>†</sup>

If you also want to have names available in the subroutine then pass a hash (or a hashref), with suitably chosen key names for variables, and in the sub work with key names.

Alternatively, consider normally declaring your variables ahead of the function call.  There's no bad thing about it while there are many good things. Can throw in a little wrapper and make it look nice, too.

---

<sup>†</sup> More specifically

```
printf "The document is: %s\n", a( do {
    my $c = 1;
    my $d = $c + 1;
    my $e = b( "use", $c, "to declare d=", $d );
    # Return a list from this `do`, which is then passed as arguments to a()
    "declare c=", $c, $e, "use the result", $d,"and document the procedure", $e 
} );
```

(condensed into fewer lines for posting here)

This `do` block is a half-way measure toward moving this code into a subroutine, as I presume that there are reasons to want this inlined.  However, since comments indicate that the reality is even more complex I'd urge you to write a normal sub instead (in which a graph can be built, btw).

Comment: I like the idea, but as soon as braces `{…}` are used, the variable is scoped and cannot be used elsewhere. In the original example, variable `$e` is declared inside function argument list of `b` – and this is where the declaration with `my` should be, but then used again in the enclosing function call to `a`.

Comment: @BernhardBodenstorfer Well ... you declare and initialize in the needed order, so `my $c = 1; my $d = $c + 1`, and then `my $e = b( ... $d ...)`.  Finally you return all such suitably built arguments, in the needed order. So last statement in the `do` block is `"...", $c, $e, "...", $d, "...", $e` (where `"..."` indicate those literal strings with text.)  That's indicated with `my $y = func2($x);` in the answer.

Comment: @BernhardBodenstorfer So everything is worked out in the block, in a normal piece of Perl code. I use `do` block so that we can in the end "return" the values that have been built -- the last line merely "returns" the variables as a list, as needed to actually pass to the sub.

Comment: @BernhardBodenstorfer None of the variables need to "_be used elsewhere_" -- you only need to build a list of scalars to eventually pass as arguments, what the last line of `do` does.   Again, if you were to actually need variables _inside the sub_ as well then pass a hashref instead (but you don't mention that and didn't answer a question asking about it so I take it that you don't need that)

Comment: @BernhardBodenstorfer Added code at the end to clarify what I mean

Comment: In a document graph, calls can be very deeply nested, think of chapters, sections, paragraphs, figures, … Clearly, the variables declared in the outermost `do` block can be accessed throughout, however the declaration should be at a place as natural as possible, for example where the figure is shown. Your call to `b` might be required long before that, thus out of context.

Comment: @BernhardBodenstorfer   I see.  Lexicals cannot do that -- what you describe is a defining property of global variables: they are created as encountered and seen throughout.  (Just can't create a lexical inside a function call and have it be seen before it or some such.) Then I'd definitely suggest to move all that out of the call statement, into a sub with proper code (my `do` is a half-way measure toward that) where you handle all that.  And btw, if it's _that_ complicated then why not just create a graph (see CPAN), instead of mucking about with variables?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument list makes two references each to `$c`, `$d` and `$e`. If you prefix the first reference with `my`, <strike>it will be out of scope by the time Perl gets around to parsing the second reference</strike> it won't be in scope until the next statement, so the second reference would refer to a different variable (which may violate `strict vars`).

Declare `my ($c,$d,$e)` before your function call. There is nothing wrong or inelegant about doing that.

Comment: it's not that it's out of scope, it's that it is not in scope yet.

my returns the variable, so it can be used immediately that way, but other than that its scope (where it can be referred to by name) doesn't begin until the following statement.

Comment: If I prefix all references to `$c`, `$d`, `$e` with `my`, perl complains `"my" variable … masks earlier declaration in same statement`.

Comment: Yes,  calling `func(my $a=1, my $a)` passes two different variables to the function.

Comment: It probably would, but the reaction of perl indicates that perl still knows at the second `my` that there is a previous declaration of that variable, so it is still in scope, isn't it.